# Tips on effective text structures for writing answers

Tags: discussion, answers, writing-style

Pretty much anyone who visits data-analysis tags ([sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), etc) will understand that a high proportion of open questions are combinations of <=5 other answers. The difficulty is in finding them and ensuring they are answered appropriately. Then, if you have the guts to link 3 wildly different duplicate targets, deal with the wrath of a user who isn't willing or able to either (a) link their question to the answers, or (b) combine logic from the duplicate targets.

I've come to the conclusion that the *only* way I can add value in this space (*not* obvious one-question duplicates) is explaining what I'm doing and why. Possibly, offer and analyse alternative approaches. The explanation part could be a couple of sentences. It could be a paragraph. This question is about **tips on style**. Yes, it's highly opinionated and subjective, and everyone has their own style, but I'm looking for experience-based knowledge of what helps most.

I've seen a variety of styles being used:

1. **Logical progression**. Starting from building blocks (e.g. tuples are immutable, lists are not, etc) and then applying them to the question.
2. **Deep-dive a solution**. Then explain why it works. Inviting, potentially, the user to use your logic without understanding it. But good for reference / review.
3. **Heading-based approach**. Give a heading for each part of your explanation (or for each alternative method). Seen this done many times to good effect; especially well in data analysis where multiple approaches are possible.

Are there others? Which do you find most useful? Can you give specific examples? [No very recent answers, please, don't want to introduce the Meta Effect.]

I've seen a lot in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), but I don't often come across (simply because I'm not looking for them) excellent answers in other tags. So, as well as discussion and pointers, links to **paragons of high-quality answers** are greatly appreciated.

**Duplicate alert**: This question on MSE is a bit too high-level for me, and the answers a little sparse: [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question). My question is, in part, a counterpoint to [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers).

Comment: Kind of a template for answers ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier, Well, that would be tough. Every question's different, don't think we can *ever* have a universal template. But more *approaches* and *examples of great uses* for each approach. I feel as though a huge number of popular questions are one-liners, but equally valuable are high-quality answers with fewer views.

Comment: Hmm, too broad? I'm not sure how I can focus it more. By its nature, my question *will be broad*. Narrowing it further would defeat the point.

Comment: This is the place for being too broad !

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Indeed: this is not *too* broad for this place. Folks should refrain from moderating Meta as if it were the main site.

Comment: Is this meant to be something like https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, No, not really. I was hoping my specific questions would help: `Are there others? Which do you find most useful? Can you give specific examples?` In my experience, an example can demonstrate much more than an explanation.

Comment: @duplode The question is *textbook* too broad.  Questions on meta don't just ignore all quality standards for...reasons.  It's literally impossible to answer the question, "how do you write a quality question" in the scope of an answer here.  The entire meta site is almost entirely dedicated to solving that exact problem.  All of the problems with incredibly broad questions on main exist on meta.  Talking about the site, and not programming, doesn't do anything to alleviate those problems.

Comment: @Servy, I identified 3 categories, there may be a couple more. I mean, there aren't an *infinite* number of *ways* you can answer a question. Broad, maybe. Incredibly broad, maybe not?

Comment: @jpp I *would* say there are an infinite ways, but even if the number is finite, it's still *well* beyond the acceptable or even allowable scope for an answer on the site.  I would say that it's literally impossible to ask a broader (on topic) question on this site, given that pretty much the entirety of meta is dedicated to trying to improve the quality of questions, in different ways.

Comment: @Servy Scope is not the only difference between Meta and the main site. After all, pretty much everything under [discussion] would be formally unacceptable on the main site. Open-ended discussions are acceptable here. Furthermore, the final paragraphs of this question make it significantly narrower than "how do you write a quality \[answer\]".

Comment: @jpp, is that the bar for broadness? Infinity? I always thought it was a bit lower, like *at most* 2,147,483,647 answers. ;-).

Comment: @duplode What the question is actually asking is made rather explicit: "Are there others? Which do you find most useful? Can you give specific examples?"  It'a asking for what people find useful in asking good questions, specific examples of good questions, and other advice on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @Servy, Except this is about answering, not asking.

Comment: @jpp Oh, well in that case, it's fine, because there aren't lots of different factors in writing quality answers, and you can write everything you could possibly want to know about how to write a quality answer in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @Servy "What the question is actually asking is made rather explicit [...]" -- Indeed, *and that is okay*. I understand this question as starting an open-ended discussion about effective ways to structure answers, and we should be able to have that discussion here.

Comment: @duplode It's okay for questions here to not have definitively correct answers, and to be discussions rather than strictly questions without answers.  That doesn't mean scope is irrelevant and it's appropriate or useful to ask a question that so *incredibly* broad that it couldn't possibly be answered, even with an entire book.  Questions need to be more specific than that to be useful, even on meta.

Comment: Honestly, the original title was fine. You reach a certain point of spelling things out where it starts getting unnecessarily verbose *and* awkward.

Comment: @BoltClock, Yeh I guess this is to stave off the close-voters. Trying to make it *reflect* the post's specificity.

Comment: @jpp: How I resent this state of affairs (with the site as a whole).

Comment: @BoltClock Seconded. There are days in which I feel like posting a Meta rant along the lines of "Stop conforming to literalism!", but then a question like this one comes in and I find myself doing it too. It is quite demoralising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One pattern I find myself using somewhat often is kind of an hybrid of the approaches you mention. Applying it would result in answers with three movements:

1. A concise explanation of the core issue involved in the question;
2. The solution itself, which addresses the matter discussed in #1; and
3. The fine print: extra detail that would be distracting in initial explanation, caveats of the offered solution, suggestions of alternative approaches, relevant but tangential advice to the OP, and so forth.

This is far from being a template (it is not applicable everywhere, and manifests itself in fluid ways); rather, it is more like an "ideal type" of sorts.

For the sake of illustration, here is [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696999/2751851) in which the pattern is reasonably easy to spot. It also demonstrates another text structure trick I find helpful: liberal use of blockquotes from the question to make it clear which aspects of the question are being addressed on each passage. It can be an useful alternative to section headers, especially for relatively short answers.

Comment: I like the idea of quoting parts of the question itself in your answer. Relatively underused IMO. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @jpp: My answers may appeal to you.

Comment: Also, block-quoting can make relatively short answers appear longer :-D

Comment: @Bergi: I wanted to see how many answers I've posted with at least one Yes/No answer to a quote. Not many at all. You on the other hand have *dozens* of answers like that :D (and Quentin has almost twice as many) http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/861892/quoted-part-questions-with-one-word-yes-no-answers

Comment: @BoltClock None of them consist of *only* a Yes/No response though :-) Maybe 15 of them have only one explaining sentence, most of them are considerably longer. [Same query, sorted by length of post](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/862037/quoted-part-questions-with-one-word-yes-no-answers?UserId=1048572).